# jQuery .mousedown() and .click()

Tags: jquery

I have a `div`. There is an image in that `div`. `mousedown()` method is attached to that div. On the other hand `.click()` method is attached to that image.

When I click on the image the `.mousedown()` method start working. But I would like to stop that `.mousedown()` and start `.click()` method . How can I do that ??

Thanks

Comment: Is anything being done on mousedown? If not, simply remove that binding. Or is it like "if the user presses down the mouse anywhere inside the DIV, but not over the image, then run mouseDown(), else do img.click()" ??

Comment: @techfoobar 
if the user presses down the mouse anywhere inside the DIV, but not over the image, then run mouseDown(), else do img.click()

Exactly.

Comment: In that case, roasted's solution should work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

This is what i understand you want to do:

```
$('img').mousedown(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: you forgot to pass the 'e' down in the function. (function(e){)

Comment: This will totally negate the mousedown. But its possible the OP wants something done on mousedown, why else would that event be attached to the div?